# Are questions about Youtubers/streamers on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I just read [this question about finding a Youtuber playing Monster Hunter Generation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357374/do-any-body-know-any-you-tubers-that-still-play-mhgen) and I was wondering:

**Are Q&A's about finding a Youtuber or streamer who's playing a specific game on topic?**

I remember [this meta about whether or not Discord Q&A's are on topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/are-questions-about-discord-on-topic), of which the [accepted answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12990/228547) tells us:

> Discord is not specifically gaming-related. However, it is very heavily used by gamers and referenced in gaming culture.
>   I would be OK making a rule to explicitly allow Discord questions, even though it wouldn't normally fall under our generally strict umbrella.

Someone could argue that videos or streams about video games are pretty focused and could fit within the same range.

However, there may be a separation between general video creators on YouTube and those making use of stream services: streams are mostly used for games (pretty much exactly the same case as for Discord), while YouTube host a very huge variety of categories of videos.

Answer (score 7):

Asking about youtube/streaming/recording is perfectly fine and on topic, we have a decent handful of questions about [Fraps](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraps) and [streaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streaming) that are well received and answerable. The posted question is asking for a *recommendation* on youtubers, which we don't do reccs here. Their question could be salvaged to ask about something like capturing or editing. Be wary about asking editing styles, though, as that is likely Opinion Based.