# Are questions about Twitch on topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I read a question on here with an answer saying that if a topic is mostly about video games then it's okay. So are questions about Twitch on topic?

Comment: Related: [Are questions about Discord on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12989/47878)

Comment: Also, we already have questions about [Teamspeak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamspeak) and [Skype](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Asking section of the Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities

Based on this, the questions can fall into two (or more?) categories:

#### Questions about Streamers

They are off topic as they don't fall on the already mentioned categories. Plus, they might attract low quality, speculative and opinion based answers.

#### The features of Twitch and the Desktop App

I would say that they are on topic (Game-specific hardware and utilities) as long as they are connected to a game, for example:

- How do I claim my Twitch Prime content on [Game Name]?
- How can I play the games that I have claimed on Twitch?
- How can I download a Minecraft Mod from the Twitch Desktop App?
- How can I show what hero I'm using in Overwatch while streaming on Twitch?

Comment: Also allowed, is gameplay questions using Twitch as a reference: *"How do I perform the double jump up this wall as shown by this streamer?"*

Answer (score -3):

I'd say it's about as on-topic as questions about your television or ESPN would be if they happen to be hosting some e-sports.

Which is to say, not really on topic at all.