# Are questions about running non-games on gaming hardware on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, gaming-hardware

To elaborate on my question take the Steam Deck, which is designed as a handheld console, however, does have a "desktop" environment and *can* be used as a PC. From the tour I understand that questions about the Steam Deck would be on-topic, as it's gaming hardware, but what if the question itself isn't about games on the device?

For example, what if someone wanted to know how to install a PDF Reader on the device and (maybe) then use that within "gaming mode"?

This isn't limited to the Steam Deck, I've just used it as an example. If I recall correctly, an Xbox can (or could) have Windows Apps installed on it if you are in developer mode, so if someone was asking about that I assume that could be on-topic too.

I note that questions about Discord appear to be [on-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/are-questions-about-discord-on-topic), so would the answer change *if* the question were about Discord and the console/device?

Comment: What is the *actual* question you wish to ask? Can you include that for another example?

Comment: I, personally, wanted to know if anyone knew how to run the non-Flatpak version of Discord (which can be downloaded in a `.tar.gz` file) to run on a Steam Deck by launching it *from* Steam on the device, @TimmyJim . I can get the app to run without issue outside of Steam (on the Steam Deck), but not from Steam. I, however, did intentionally generalise the question, as I specifically didn't want to use the link question on Discord as a reason to make it on-topic, and I can envision other similar qusetions in the future as adoption of the device grows.

Comment: Another possible topic could be web browsers on various consoles. Some (e.g. 3DS) come with built-in web browsers, others have ways to install them (which might or might not require rooting). A question might be, "Why do I get an Error A4B when trying to login to my online banking at [site] with the 3DS browser? Can this be fixed or does the 3DS lack support for some neccessary technology?"

Comment: The thing is I can see the question I want to ask being on-topic per the [tour], and likely in the [help/on-topic] but I'm not sure if it's really within the *spirit* of what is on-topic, hence me wanting to try and gauge people's opinions. The alternative, I suppose, could be I take the time to post the question and it ends up setting precedence (depending on if the question is well received or not), but as someone unfamiliar with [main] I don't know how well that could be received.

Comment: An additional topic could be the GlucoBoy, which is medical equipment that connects to the GBA and turns the whole thing into a medical device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm inclined to say that your [actual question regarding Discord and the Steam Deck](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/are-questions-about-running-non-games-on-gaming-hardware-on-topic#comment48867_16602) would be valid for our site since we already established both Steam Deck and Discord questions as being acceptable.  I consider Discord a *Game-specific utility* which is pointed out in our [help pages](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

But your example about *how to install a PDF Reader on the device and (maybe) then use that within "gaming mode"?* I don't know... I can't see that really being valid for the site.  I would need to understand how this "gaming mode" part works, and how a PDF Reader could be used in the context of "gaming" (I don't see any way currently).  This sounds more like a general software installation question.

Comment: Discord specifically was discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12989/28182)

Comment: So, in the statement *"Game-specific hardware and utilities"* being on topic, the sentence is actually saying that the question must be *both*, for it to be on topic, rather than about gaming utilises *or* game-specific hardware, is what I am understanding from this?

Comment: @Larnu I read _Game-specific hardware and utilities_ as it must be about one OR both.  Not strictly both.

Comment: Following that train of thought: if I connect a PS4 controller to a tractor to play Doom and have questions about this, it is potentially on-topic? And when I turn my PS4 into a Network Video Server, this could work too? I'd probably agree with the first, but I have my doubts about the value of allowing the second.

Comment: @Mast those are pretty specific topics. I guess it would depend on if you had a question about the tractor or controller...? I'd probably say your video server question would be more suitable.

Comment: Instead of trying to draw lines on what is valid, you should ask if your actual question would be on topic here on meta. It's easier to determine that way.